# HttpWebRequest only running on .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, vb.net, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, httpwebrequest

I got a strange problem or even behaviour with a WebRequest. First and foremost, here's what I'm trying to do:

```vb
Dim req As HttpWebRequest = CType(Net.WebRequest.Create("https://cloud.myweb.de/myenginge/dostuff"), HttpWebRequest)

Dim inputString As String = "text=DoStuff"
Dim data As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputString)

req.Method = "POST"
req.Accept = "application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"

req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
req.ContentLength = data.Length

str2 = req.GetRequestStream()

str2.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
str2.Close()

Dim resp As HttpWebResponse = CType(req.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
str = resp.GetResponseStream()
buffer = New IO.StreamReader(str, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII).ReadToEnd
```

But having the .NET Frame 3.5 set in my compile settings will lead to a timeout in:

```vb
str2 = req.GetRequestStream()
```

while setting the Framework Version 4.0 works and everything passes without any timeout issue. Does anybody know why this happens? I tried 3.0 as well, and it didn't work either.

(I'm using VB.NET in this example, but C# solutions are also welcome.)

Comment: Use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to see what the differences are in the request.  Technically, if the requests are exactly identical, then the remote server shouldn't know the difference to be able to respond in different ways.  Either the requests are different in some minor point, or the different frameworks are handling the same response two different ways.

Comment: ok, I will try Fiddler in a first step. Thanks for that hint

Comment: If you set `req.Timeout` to a value higher than the timeout you're experiencing, does it work then? +1 for fiddler though, at least you can see if it's actually sending the request and if there are any differences with it.

Comment: You should be using Fiddler anyway as its a great tool for debugging web requests, however, I dont think it's going to help you in this scenario. Your saying the timeout is happening when you call 'GetRequestStream' on the request *before* you have even sent anything to the server.

Comment: @James: The request should still show in fiddler, but no response will ever come.  So you should still be able to compare the two requests, and try modifying them and re-running in Fiddler to see what the triggers are for the problem.

Comment: @mellamokb I wouldn't have thought anything would have appeared in fiddler until you called 'GetResponseStream'? I am not in front of my machine to test

Comment: @James: A quick test proves you are correct :)  Once again my understanding of network requests has been duly refined.  Back to the drawing board...

Comment: Yeah thought as much, 'GetRequestStream' just gets a stream to write data into the request that all happens client side. @Inva Is it possible you have another request open which hasn't been closed/disposed beforehand?

Comment: Hm, I think I will have to get in touch with Fiddler into more detail ... If I have Fiddler running, it does not matter which framework version I'm using, everything will end up at GetResponseStream with an exception telling me that the connection was closed and an unknown error occured. (if I'm using 4.0 and no fiddler, it's working properly, but using fiddler inbetween will let it fail)

Comment: @Inva - think thats a common problem with Fiddler. It switches the proxy settings which can end up blocking the request, you can change these options in fiddler (can't remember the exact steps it's in the Fiddler help). Like I said, Fiddler isn't going to help you for now as your not even getting the request away yet. Your issue is actually creating the request itself. So is there a possibility of previous requests being left open? My guess is it is, try wrapping your calls with the using statement this will make sure it all gets tidied up for you instead of manually calling 'Close()'

Comment: I don't think so, it's exactly the same code i'm using on both platforms (e.g. 4.0 and 3.5) and on 4.0 it's working properly. Furthermore there is only the code stated above in my question which is used. Therefore no other WebRequests are used so far.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is you have some other request sitting open which hasn't been disposed of yet. Update your code to use the `using` statement where applicable (you should always use this when dealing with any objects which implement `IDisposable`) e.g.

```
using (var stream = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    ...
}
```

This will make sure all streams are closed reliably before moving onto the next.

**Update**

This is definitely not an issue with switching the .NET Framework, I sandboxed your code into a small console app and re-wrote the code as follows (obviously switching out your URL for a different one):

```
Dim request = CType(WebRequest.Create("https://cloud.myweb.de/myenginge/dostuff"), HttpWebRequest)
Dim data As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("text=DoStuff")
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post
request.Accept = "application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
request.ContentLength = data.Length
Using inputStream = request.GetRequestStream()
    inputStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length)
End Using

Dim response = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
Dim buffer As String = ""
Using outputStream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Using streamReader = New StreamReader(outputStream, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII)
        buffer = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
    End Using
End Using
Console.WriteLine(buffer)
```

And I got a successful response back everytime. I ran the same code under both .NET 4.0 & 3.5. Here's how each request looked courtesy of [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler2/):

> **POST** someurl HTTP/1.1
>   **Accept**: application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
>   **Content-Type**: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>   **Host**: someurl
>   **Content-Length**: 12 
>   **Expect**: 100-continue
>  
>   **Connection**: Keep-Alive
>
> text=DoStuff

Comment: I will try this for now, actually wrappen such things is generally a good idea. But as I said, using version 4.0 works, but no version less than 4.0 sends the request :(

Comment: using this wrapping idea does not solve my problem - i can't figure out that there are any open requests. it's just the code executed shown above. furthermore i wrapped my cock using a lock() statement (or even SyncLock in Vb.net) but this does not helped too.

Comment: @inva You may want to re-read your last statement again lol Re-write it with the code I have updated my answer with and see if that solves the problem. Your inital code was leaving streams open (even on the result of an exception) which can cause the thread pool to run out of connections to serve. Is it a possibility that this issue could be coming from the server? Do you have control over the server side of things?

Comment: @alex - we both spotted that lol I guess he can at least say he tried EVERYTHING!

Comment: @James mymy I almost fell off the chair

Comment: @Alex of cause! i did my very best ... i guess it was an unfortunately accident ;)

Comment: @James I tried your code and i'm supposed that the code shall be working, but i still got a timeout after calling GetRequestStream - so if not server contact is triggered with this call (as i red from your former posts) i'm not having any idea what else is going wrong.

Comment: Is it possible that my server on the other side closes the connection to fast?

Comment: @inva - Your server won't have received anything yet, I suggest you enable tracing and see what you get in the logs - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty48b824(VS.80).aspx.

Comment: @James thanks a lot for your commitment! I figured out, that there is a proxy server right in front of the web service ... passing this proxy by (just using the internal ip of the actual server) will work for me and any .NET Version ... therefore, it seems to be related to this proxy somehow.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `request.Proxy` property of the request?

Comment: @James no not yet - man, there are that much properties to set ^^

Comment: @James the direct address (using the proxy in front) is using https, i guess thats not possible to use as proxy settings =/

Comment: @James i tried setting the proxy property, but actually it does not work and instead is it usefull to use that? i mean: the proxy is right before the web service on server side, not on my side

Comment: Ah ok, not sure it would work in that scenario then, I think the Proxy property is more for if you have a proxy for connecting to the web. IF you can live with using the internal IP I would just go with that.

Comment: @James - it's not nice but it works actually. But i'm quite a little bit unhappy and confused that if works using the internal IP, because the server based proxy shall not be requested at the time i'm calling GetRequestStream =(

Answer (score 0):

I would compare the IL code of your exe files using [ILSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/MainPage.ashx).
Maybe an inspection on this level gives you an idea where things differ between the versions.